# How could I query embed object field name in mongodb / pymongo?

Tags: pymongo, mongodb-query

My users' collection used to like:

```
{'_id':'xxx', 'hobbies':['Dance','Ski']}
```

Now I add "likes" as:

```
{'_id':'xxx', 'hobbies':{'Dance':5,'Ski':8}}
```

I want to query users have at least one same hobby, my old query is like:

```
db.usr.find({'_id':{'$ne':usr['_id']}, 'hobbies':{'$in':usr['hobbies']} })
```

Now my query is like:

```
db.usr.find({'_id':{'$ne':usr['_id']}, 
             'hobbies':{'$in':list(usr['hobbies'].keys())} })
```

I checked out mongodb documents, found nothing to represent 'hobbies' field name, or python's dictionary key. For mongodb, new 'hobbies' represents embed object, the field name is usually definite.

Do I HAVE TO maintain two arrays(in mongodb) or lists(in python)? Isn't there a simple solution?

```
{'_id':'xxx', 'hobbies':['Dance','Ski'], 'likes':[5,8]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfotunately, mongodb does not support querying/filtering *field names*.

Your options are:

1. do the filtering on client side, after querying in full
2. keep hobbies names in an array, like you used to, in order to be able to filter on server side